# Extract R^2 from survreg model

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I'm doing a `survreg` model and want to have an idea about its performance so I want to see its r-squared. If found the perfect function for this: `pam.survreg`. However, I get the error:

`Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : 'Column1' not found`

Any idea why?

Comment: You defined column called `Column1` in your model call, but `Column1` doesn't exist in the data set.

Comment: It's in the dataset. I'm sure. I should have given more info, sorry. The function I ran was `pam.survreg(survival_model)` and `survival_model` was trained on a dataset that definitely contains `Column1`

Comment: Did you specify x = TRUE, y = TRUE in your model?